# Debian Package Manager Problem

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

When I install something or update something I get the following error messages:

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                         Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

But when I type `apt-get -f install`:

```
(Reading database ... 32387 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.20-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.20-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp', which is also in package apache2.2-bin 2.2.22-13+deb7u6
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do?

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://froxlormirror.netcup.net/froxlor-nc/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release o=netcup Froxlor,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=inoffical froxlor packac=main
     origin froxlormirror.netcup.net
 500 http://froxlormirror.netcup.net/froxlor/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release o=froxlor.org,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Froxlor Repository,c=main
     origin froxlormirror.netcup.net
 500 http://debian.froxlor.org/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release o=froxlor.org,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Froxlor Repository,c=main
     origin debian.froxlor.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ sid/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=oldstable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.11,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to (at least) remove `apache2.2-bin`:

```
apt-get remove apache2.2-bin
```

Alternatively, you can force the installation of `apache2-bin`:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-2_amd64.deb
```

and then try `apt-get -f install` again.

Comment: When i do that then comes this:` libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                         Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: @Ralph try forcing `dpkg` to overwrite (see my updated answer).

Comment: @Ralph try  `aptitude -f install`

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6-base : Breaks: gcc-4.7-base (< 4.7.3) but 4.7.2-5 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gcc-4.7-base [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]

Comment: @Ralph GCC 6? What version of Debian are you running? Could you [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/292832/edit) your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: The Output is too long XD.

Comment: I'm guessing you added testing and unstable to be able to install PHP 7, is that correct?

Comment: yes thats right.

Comment: welcome to the exciting world of being a beta-tester for debian.  if you don't know how to deal with minor problems like this, don't use testing or unstable.  stick to stable and maybe some selected backports.